# Using GD library for captcha, image is not shown

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I am using a GD library to generate captcha image. But the image is not showing up. Can you please help me with it.
This is a text converted to captcha image 
index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['secure']=rand(1000,9999);
?>

<img src="generate.php" />
```

generate.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$text = $_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size=30;

$image_width=200;
$image_height=40;

$image = imagecreate($image_width,$image_height );
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

These above are the two files with which I am trying to generate a captcha image. But the image is not showing up. My GD library is enabled, i have had a check on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert GD output to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551754/convert-gd-output-to-base64)

Comment: Does `font.ttf` exist? Try removing the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` statement and navigate to generate.php with your browser, it should help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: font.ttf is in the same folder

Comment: Somebody please answer i am badly stuck

Answer (score 0):

[From documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

So try something like:

$font = "/path_to_folder/font.ttf";

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, $font, $text);

This work for me.